# How can you change from UTM to Lon/Lat for a watershed shapefile in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude, shapefile, utm

I am trying to change the X and Y component for a watershed shape file to Lon and Lat. I was thinking this would be as simple as the following:

```
W8 = shaperead(WBD_HU_08_IA.shp,'UseGeoCoords',false);
nrrb = W8(27) % this gives the polygon info for the North Raccoon River Basin only 
>Geometry: 'Polygon'
>BoundingBox: [2x2 double]
>          X: [1x14530 double]
>          Y: [1x14530 double]
>     REGION: 'Upper Mississippi R…'
>      ...
>     FIPS_C: ' 19161 19121 19147 …'
```

Where X and Y are in UTM:

```
  >BondingBox =

    >1.0e+06 *

    >0.3104    4.5928
    >0.4490    4.7554
```

By changing 'UseGeoCoords' = true, the following occurs:

```
W8 = shaperead(WBD_HU_08_IA.shp,'UseGeoCoords',true); 
nrrb = W8(27)

>Geometry: 'Polygon'
>BoundingBox: [2x2 double]
>        Lon: [1x14530 double]
>        Lat: [1x14530 double]
>     REGION: 'Upper Mississippi R…'
      ...
>     FIPS_C: ' 19161 19121 19147 …'
```

Where the BoundingBox, Lat, and Lon should change from UTM to degrees, but does not occur.

I am currently stuck and do not know what else to do to get these units to convert. I have tried using the code for utm2deg, utm2ll, MappingToolbox, etc. which do not seem to work. I keep getting errors that

```
ZONE must be integer value, scalar or same size as X and/or Y.
```

when I set my zone = '15N' which is what it is for the NRRB. I even created a loop to put '15N' into an array to make it the same size as X and Y which gave me an error saying

```
Too many input arguments.
```

My end goal is to convert UTM to degrees so I can project the outline of the NRRB watershed on my NetCDF data plots, which are in a Lon/Lat format. Any suggestions on how to fix this or get utm2deg or utm2ll to work properly would be amazing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're able to use python instead of matlab, there is a package available to convert from UTM to lat/lon: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm

Comment: I would like to stay in MATLAB because I have all of the code to analyze the .nc files written and running beautifully. Thanks for the suggestion though.